# How do i change all the values in the same row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table in SQL looks like this

```
Place        a     b      c         d      e     f
Home        null  null   null     null   null  null
Work        null  null   null     null   null  null
```

all the values are `null`. I would like the first row with `place='work'` 
to have a consistent value to `3.5`

and second row where `place='work'` will have `1.5` (has to be calculated as `3.5 - 2`)

can anyone help me to write a query that works in every number as a general form?

sometimes these two numbers might not be `3.5` and `1.5`... but `2` is always subtracted from the first number to calculate the second number.

it's in SQL 2008

The final output should look like this:

```
Place        a     b      c        d      e     f
Home        3.5   3.5    3.5      3.5    3.5   3.5
Work        1.5   1.5    1.5      1.5    1.5   1.5
```

Comment: Something seems wrong with your data structure.  Why would you have six columns all with the same value?  I suspect you should be storing things with one row per place and column.

Comment: `update ... set a=3.5, b=3.5, c=3.5, etc...`

Comment: Re: "first" and "second" Does this table only have those two rows?

Comment: What is the point of this table?

Comment: Sorry, but it's for reporting purpose. I just came up with similar data structure but that's basically what I need to do... changing entire rows with same value. I thought about putting it as a one column and transpose the table. would that work better?

Comment: You say that you want *the first row with `place='work'`* to have one value, and the second to have another based on the first.  1.  You don't have two `work` rows in your sample set.  And 2. How are you determining the order of those rows?  SQL, by its very nature, represents *undordered* sets.  If you don't specify a way to order something, *the order is not guaranteed*.

Comment: I see. Thank you. probably will need to find a better way...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableName
SET a='3.5'
,b='3.5'
,c='3.5'
,d='3.5'
,e='3.5'
,f='3.5'
WHERE Place = 'Home'
```